# Typescript how to reverse a Dictionary after JSon.stringify

Tags: angular, typescript, web-worker

When I use web worker to postMessage(obj), I tried to transfer a dictionary object in this way.

```
let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(workerMessage));
this.worker.postMessage(obj);
```

Received on the other end, I can see there are items in the obj but cannot call Dictionary methods. Then I used this way to loop through it. Still feel not convenient.

```
let values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) {
            return obj[k];
        });
```

Is it possible to cast the obj back to Dictionary and then operate it in Dictionary way.

Tried this, does not work.

```
dicData= value.data.obj as Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, custom>>;
```

Comment: Javascript does not have a dictionary object. Do you mean a plain object or some custom Object you created?

Comment: In this case, I am using custom object as values in dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stringify methods inside an Object in javascript. `JSON.stringify()` will omit functions or convert them to null. More about this in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description).

I suggest you send just parameters through with postMessage. The logic to handle these parameters should already exist on the other side.

Comment: Yes, agree. But my dataset is quite big and I need their key/value pair relations. Actually, the structure of the dictionary stays after stringify when received them from the other side, for example, it converted arrays with the items which contains the keys and values as expected. And that is why I am thinking if there is a better way to cast them and use the pairs.

Comment: Maybe I didnt't understand your question right. Could you show an example of your dictionary object? There is no problem in serializing arrays and nested key/value pairs. But you cannot serialize a function with its body.

Comment: Thanks, guys. My dictionary object is like <key, dictionary<key, value>>. When they are serialized, it would become an array with {key : items} and the items with structure is {key : value}. So, I am using the way like object.items[key] to get the value from the other end, kind of solve the issue. I guess if I really want to use it in a dictionary, I have to rebuild a dict by looping through it.